# Excel formula in VF pages

Tags: visualforce

Any help on the below issue is well appreciated.

I am using the below excel formula to concatenate 2 cell strings (i.e str1-str2). Excel is loading with warning in the table saying 'Bad formula found'

```
<Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="21">
    <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s81" ss:Formula="=RC[16]&amp;&quot;-&quot;&amp;RC[17]"><Data
      ss:Type="String"></Data><NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>
</Row>
```

RC[16]&"-"&RC[17] - During the download excel is unable to translate as =RC[16]&"-"&RC[17] hence my formula is not getting loaded. It is showing &amp as &#38

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackExchange. Could you include the VF page on your question? Possibly reduced to only focus on this particular issue. That will help in figuring out the solution.

Comment: <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="0" ss:Height="21">
    <Cell ss:Index="3" ss:StyleID="s81" ss:Formula="=RC[16]&amp;&quot;-&quot;&amp;RC[17]"><Data
      ss:Type="String">00274326-00000001</Data><NamedCell ss:Name="Print_Area"/></Cell>

Comment: Hi Clairbois, I specified the formula that has issue. My VF page is long with lot of formulas in it. All the formulas are working well except where the concatenation exists.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! M. Clairbois made the edit for you this time, moving the details from your comment into your question post. In the future, please do not answer questions posted in the comments, or add other helpful information, in the comments. Instead, edit your original post to answer/add info. This keeps all info in one place for future readers, and reduces the chances that a potential helper misses helpful info.

Comment: Hi Tanuja. What you put here is how it appears in the final file, right? Or is this your visualforce page? I can't help you without seeing the actual visualforce code.

Comment: Hi Clairbois, the markup that i put here is one formula with XML escape characters from XML spreadsheet. i copied our entire XML spreadsheet with all formulas in VF page for the user to download from VF page using button click(also used to apex:repeat to reference salesforce data).  xls file is getting downloaded with all data but for the formulas where special characters are refered(example above) like (quotation, hypen,colon, semicolon) are unable to output in xls file, it says bad formula found.

Comment: Hi Clairbois, Please find the VF page here https://github.com/tanujaanvitha/FormulaTest.git. As specified above, &amp;&quot; are rendering in excel when it got downloaded using VF page button